# search for a word in file and replace it with the corresponding value from dictionary in python

Tags: python

I want to search for a word from some file and replace that word with different string from the dictionary of keywords. It's basically just text replacement thing.

My code below doesn't work:

```
keyword = {
    "shortkey":"longer sentence",
  "gm":"goodmorning",
  "etc":"etcetera"

}

with open('find.txt', 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        if re.search(keyword.keys(), line):         
            file.write(line.replace(keyword.keys(), keyword.values()))
            break
```

The error message when I write `print`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "py.py", line 42, in <module>
    if re.search(keyword.keys(), line):         
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 146, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 237, in _compile
    p, loc = _cache[cachekey]
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: Do you want to write to a file that you have opened in read-only mode?

Comment: oh.. i didn't notice. but anyway, even when i want to print the output, it gives an error

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: What is the error message? It would be great if you put it in your question as an edition. :-)

Comment: – eyllanesc – GKE edited the question.

Comment: The keys() function converts your keys to a list.

Comment: @valeria If you have another question, we invite you to create another post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Editing a file in place is dirty; you would be better off writing to a new file, and, afterward, replacing your old file.

You are attempting to use a list as a regex, which isn't valid. I'm not sure why you are using regex in the first place, as it's not necessary. You also cannot pass a list into `str.replace`.

You can iterate over the list of keywords and check each one against the string.

```py
keyword = {
    "shortkey": "longer sentence",
    "gm": "goodmorning",
    "etc": "etcetera"
}

with open('find.txt', 'r') as file, open('find.txt.new', 'w+') as newfile:
    for line in file:
        for word, replacement in keyword.items():
            newfile.write(line.replace(word, replacement))

# Replace your old file afterwards with the new one
import os
os.rename('find.txt.new', 'find.txt')
```

Comment: `with open('find.txt', 'r') as file, open('find.txt.new', 'w+') as newfile:` is a bit more compact.

Comment: Also, don't read all lines at once in beginning. `for line in file` would do.

Comment: great!! it works, but the thing is.. i need to replace the keyword in the first file, not to write it in another. how can i do it the proper way then?

Comment: Judging by the name "keywords", OP does not want to replace "augment" with "augoodmorningent".

Comment: @Valeria, you can't shift the bytes in a file, only overwrite them (actually you can, but it's not worth the effort for this. Trust me). Hence the advice to write a new temporary file and replace the existing one when you're done. That's how virtually every program does it. When you hit Ctrl+S, most of the time you aren't just saving. You're also replacing.

Comment: Updated answer to include moving the file @valeria, as well as incorporating other comments.

Comment: wrt keywords being words, solution, depending on the format of valeria's file, could be `line.replace(f' {word} ', f' {replacement} ')`

Comment: @raindrop. Not a good idea since it will miss the first and last word, as well as any other delimiters.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, raindrop thanks for contributing! may I ask one more question? how can I make it so that the code automatically changes the word into its longer value without having to run it in the terminal every time I write the shortkey? Maybe like when I press the Tab or something..? is it possible?

Comment: @valeria, I think there's easily enough scope there for another full question